# How to properly implement onFling method?

Tags: java, android

Okay,In this piece of code I get that your creating instance variables of type gesture detector which will call the FlingGestureListener.class.I'm getting the error `a super interface must be an interface` but I have created it as of type "interface".The id gives an error also when I refer it to my xml layout name.Implementing FlingGestureListner so my studentGallery class looks like this now and implements the FlingGestureListener:

```
public class GalleryStudent extends Activity implements FlingGestureLitener {

     private static final int MAJOR_MOVE = 0;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_galery_student);

            final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),
            FlingGestureListener.getInstance(tabSwipeListener));
            final ImageView peopleTab = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_galery_student);

            peopleTab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
            });
            Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
            g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(GalleryStudent.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm confused here as you are using this to naviagate to the class : `tabSwipeListener.onTabSwipe(true, PLACES_FRAGMENT);` In this case you are taking a fragment as its parameter whereas my classes aren't fragments.Is there a simple way to change my classes to fragments to accommadate this?Also the onTabSwiperListener `cannot be resolved to a type` in this case.This is the FlingGestureListener I used from your explanation which I have created as an Interface:

```
public class FlingGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
private static final int PEOPLE_FRAGMENT = 0;
private static final int PLACES_FRAGMENT = 2;
private OnTabSwipedListener tabSwipeListener;

private FlingGestureListener(OnTabSwipedListener tabSwipeListener){
    this.tabSwipeListener = tabSwipeListener;

}

/**
 * Static factory
 * @param listener called when tab swiped
 * @return
 */
public static FlingGestureListener getInstance(OnTabSwipedListener listener){
    return new FlingGestureListener(listener);
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        Log.d("SWIPE", "right to left");
        tabSwipeListener.onTabSwipe(true, PLACES_FRAGMENT); //sent int to fragment container to switch pager to that view 
        return true; //Right to left
    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        Log.d("SWIPE", "left to right");
        tabSwipeListener.onTabSwipe(true, PEOPLE_FRAGMENT);
        return true; //Left to right 
    }

    //This will test for up and down movement. 
    if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        return false; //Bottom to top
    } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        return false; //Top to bottom 
    }

    return false;
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You need to use `setOnTouchListener(...)` on something that implements the method. Any object of type `View` or subclass of `View` will do.

Comment: `return detector.onTouchEvent(event);` Inside your anonymous class, it doesn't know what "detector" is.

Comment: Could you clarify this further for me? I don't quite understand your explanation.

Comment: @user2815899 he is saying that this method is not in a class that is-a View.

Comment: still not sure how to fix this implementation...

Answer (score 1):

`onFling` is a method available to members of the `SimpleOnGestureListener` [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html). To override this method you either need to (1) create a class that extends `SimpleOnGestureListener` or (2) implement a gesture listener within your existing class. Then you can override `onFling`.

**Update**

Sorry for the delay. Here's my implementation. In the activity that you want to use the `onFling` you need to set up a `GestureDetector` that uses your custom `onFling` listener. You can see I'm using a `FlingGestureListener` the code for which is below. I'm listening for touch on a specific image, peopleTab, but you should be able to substitute any view.

```
    final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),    FlingGestureListener.getInstance(tabSwipeListener));
    final ImageView peopleTab = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.peopleFlag);

    peopleTab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Then for FlingGestureListener I use a separate class that extends `SimpleOnGestureListener` so I can choose to only implement `onFling`

```
public class FlingGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 50;
private static final int PEOPLE_FRAGMENT = 0;
private static final int PLACES_FRAGMENT = 2;
private OnTabSwipedListener tabSwipeListener;

private FlingGestureListener(OnTabSwipedListener tabSwipeListener){
    this.tabSwipeListener = tabSwipeListener;
}

/**
 * Static factory
 * @param listener called when tab swiped
 * @return
 */
public static FlingGestureListener getInstance(OnTabSwipedListener listener){
    return new FlingGestureListener(listener);
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){
    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        Log.d("SWIPE", "right to left");
        tabSwipeListener.onTabSwipe(true, PLACES_FRAGMENT); //sent int to fragment container to switch pager to that view 
        return true; //Right to left
    } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        Log.d("SWIPE", "left to right");
        tabSwipeListener.onTabSwipe(true, PEOPLE_FRAGMENT);
        return true; //Left to right 
    }

    //This will test for up and down movement. 
    if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        return false; //Bottom to top
    } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY){
        return false; //Top to bottom 
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

I use a callback from this class to indicate when a swipe has occurred. The booleans that are returned are just to indicate whether the whole touch event has been handled. Hopefully this helps.

**UPDATE 2**

With the interfaces I am using something specific to my set up.

```
tabSwipeListener.onTabSwipe(true, PLACES_FRAGMENT);
```

this indicates first that a swipe has occurred and in what direction. I use this in a 3 fragment `ViewPager` set up. From the middle page swiping right goes to a list of places and swiping left goes to a list of people. The PLACES_FRAGMENT constant for example is an integer that refers to the fragment id within the `ViewPager`. Passing back that integer I can then tell the `ViewPager` to change to display the fragment at position 2 which effectivtly moves the page.

I don't know how to give you a code example because I dont know that this is what you need to do. If you just need to detect a swipe then your interface need only pass back a boolean. If true you will know that the `onFling` method has been called and whatever threshold criteria you set have been met. You then need to handle that response appropritely within the context of your app. I don't think there is any more advice I can give you.

Comment: setOnTouchListener should be called on the view that you are detecting touches from. For example if I were looking to detect touch on an image it would be im.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){ //override methods here}

Comment: so in this case I want to set it to the whole touchable area of the activity.I'm guessing I would use:  result.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(). Do I place this snippet in my onCreate() to detect?

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure how to implement this.Could you look at my reply as I implemented that code but it's still not functioning.

Comment: Is this in a `ViewPager` or some other fling grabbing container because that will change things. Otherwise, I'd try using the outer most layout element - probably a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as my target view. Create that view in onCreate as an instance variable so you can set the gesture detector. If you cant get it ill post code when I'm back at my computer later.

Comment: ,Ok so I created an instance variable of gesture detector like this: GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(this); in OnCreate followed by my gesture listener code but its still giving errors...

Comment: I added my implementation so you can see how I made this work.

Comment: Cool,So I used your implementation but it didnt work as I'm getting errors.The errors are coming from tabSwipeListener not being recognised and setting the Id of the image view.I have updated my question to show how I implemented it.Can you give me some help with this? thanks

Comment: The listeners are interfaces. I created an interface to return true or false back to the class that was checking for onfling. Noting in there is fragment specific. Just create an interface who has a method that takes a Boolean as it's argument. If the condition in onfling is met return true through that method.

Comment: I implemented an interface also for the tabSwipeListener but I'm not sure what to do from here.Could you explain this further with a code example please?

Comment: I added some more explanatino but I don't know that I can explain this any better. You're going to need to apply this in the context of your application but I have certainly given you enough to do so.